# Text inside floated div not responsive

Tags: html, css

In the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid View</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
      font-size: 1vw;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 0 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: violet;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header {
      background-color: rgb(133, 76, 76);
      border: .01rem solid rgb(133, 76, 76);
      margin-bottom: 4%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 10%;
      right: 10%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    header h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .row {
      background-color: blueviolet;
      margin-bottom: 4%;
    }
    
    .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    
    [class*="col-"] {
      float: left;
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .col-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    
    .col-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    
    .col-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .col-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    
    .col-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    
    .col-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .col-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    
    .col-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    
    .col-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    
    .col-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    
    .col-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    
    .col-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    div#three div.col-3 {
      width: 24%;
      margin-right: 1.33%;
    }
    
    div#three div.col-3:last-of-type {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      html {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
      }
      body {
        padding-top: 17%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      html {
        font-size: 3vw;
      }
      body {
        padding-top: 17%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one" class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="three" class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The web page breaks at around `470px` (checked through device toolbar using chrome inspect). This happens as the text inside the 4 floated `divs` in the second row is not responsive and gets out of the `div` at `470px`. This is only happening when the text is inside a floated element, when I make the `divs` block element again, the text becomes responsive.

Can someone tell me why this happens ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help you. Added below mentioned CSS

```
    div#three div.col-3{
        width: 49%;
        margin: 0 0.5%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid View</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html {
      font-size: 1vw;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 0 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: violet;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header {
      background-color: rgb(133, 76, 76);
      border: .01rem solid rgb(133, 76, 76);
      margin-bottom: 4%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 10%;
      right: 10%;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    header h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .row {
      background-color: blueviolet;
      margin-bottom: 4%;
    }
    
    .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    
    [class*="col-"] {
      float: left;
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    
    .col-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    
    .col-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    
    .col-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    
    .col-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    
    .col-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    
    .col-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .col-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    
    .col-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    
    .col-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    
    .col-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    
    .col-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    
    .col-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    div#three div.col-3 {
      width: 24%;
      margin-right: 1.33%;
    }
    
    div#three div.col-3:last-of-type {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
      html {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
      }
      body {
        padding-top: 17%;
      }
      div#three div.col-3 {
        width: 49%;
        margin: 0 0.5%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      html {
        font-size: 3vw;
      }
      body {
        padding-top: 17%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
      div#three div.col-3 {
        width: 99%;
        margin: 0 0.5%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one" class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="three" class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt cupiditate, ullam, illum magnam quidem ipsam laudantium dicta autem fugit cumque laboriosam et neque consequuntur beatae? Molestiae sed id ipsam distinctio molestias asperiores,
          labore officia! Maxime dolor illo, beatae cumque rerum sint corrupti possimus sed labore.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why does it only happen for floated elements ?

Answer (score 0):

A single CSS rule can fix this issue without altering breakpoints or existing source code -

```css
div#three div.col-3{
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This does not take best practices in terms of readability for the end user into consideration but does fix the bug you're experiencing. Further tweaking with padding on .col-3 divs for mobile devices should help.

Comment: Why does it only happen for floated elements ?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-5

Review this article sub-paragraph - Problems with Floats. This will provide further information. 

It may be better to adopt a more modern solution such as Flexbox for your layout needs. I would recommend reviewing this article -

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font-size to a 'vw' value of text inside floating elements resolves the issue. But i still can't figure out why.